# parallel foreach sum with index

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Playing around with Parallel for and foreach. The following block will try to sum list of 1 million members (from -2000,2000) with either the **list Element** or the **item index**.

```cs
long sum=0;
Parallel.ForEach(
    list,
    () => // Initializer
    {
        return 0;
    },
    body: (line, state, index, subtotal) =>
    {
        int i = (int)index;
        //subtotal += i;
        subtotal += line;
        return subtotal;
    },
    localFinally: (subtotal) => // Accumulator
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
            sum += subtotal;
        }
    }
);
```

And

```cs
Parallel.For<long>(0, list.Count, () => 0, 
    (j, loop, subtotal) =>
    {
        subtotal += j;
        return subtotal;
    },
    (x) => Interlocked.Add(ref sum, x));
```

Both are compared with traditional for loop.

`Parallel.For` will return correct result on both case.

`Paralell.Foreach` will return correct result on **line** and wrong result with **index** .Note that for small set of number(<50000) , it also return correct result.

```
subtotal += line;
```

VS

```
subtotal += index;
```

What did I wrong with the foreach? Also tried using `Interlocked.add()`;

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: I tested it with `var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 65536).ToList();` and I can't reproduce it. The `Parallel.ForEach` returns the correct result 2,147,450,880 in both cases. With larger list the result is incorrect because of arithmetic overflow.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias long 'sum', should not be arithmetic overflow. List.Count = 1000000(1million).

Comment: The `sum` may be `long`, but the `subtotal` is `int`. To initialize it as a `long` you can use a [numeric literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types): `() => 0L`.